# Error DLL Oracle.DataAccess

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, oracle-11g, visual-studio-2013

Estoy utilizando la *dll* **Oracle.DataAcess** y tengo el siguiente error:

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.

No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.

Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: System.BadImageFormatException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.

Error de código fuente: 

Se ha generado una excepción no controlada durante la ejecución de la solicitud Web actual. La información sobre el origen y la ubicación de la excepción pueden identificarse utilizando la excepción del seguimiento de la pila siguiente.

Rastro al cargar el ensamblado: La información siguiente puede ser útil para determinar porqué no se cargó el ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess'.


AVS: El registro del enlace de ensamblado está desactivado.
Para habilitar el registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado, establezca el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) como 1.
Nota: existe una disminución del rendimiento asociada registro de errores del enlace de ensamblado.
Para desactivar esta característica, elimine el valor de Registro [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Seguimiento de la pila: 


[BadImageFormatException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +36
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +21
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +738
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +217
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +92
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +290
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +531

[HttpException (0x80004005): No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Oracle.DataAccess' ni una de sus dependencias. Se ha intentado cargar un programa con un formato incorrecto.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9920756
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +261
```

Qué se debe hacer para solucionar este error?

Comment: ¿Cómo instalastes el dll? Y, asumiendo que lo instalastes correctamente, ¿fue un install 32bit o 64bit? Y tu app asp.net, ¿corre en 32bit o 64bit?

Comment: Estas trabajando una aplicación con ASP.NET? A veces ocurre este tipo de errores cuando se intenta ejecutar una .dll de 32-bit en un entorno de 64-bit. Si estas trabajando con IIS asegúrate que el sitio web es compatible con aplicaciones de 32-bit.

Comment: Tenemos instalado  odp.net de 64 bits de Oracle que trae la dll Oracle.DataAcces y asp.net de 64 bits.

Comment: Y ¿cómo fue instalado el odp.net?¿Se usó un instalador estándar? ¿O fueron copiados los dlls a mano?

Comment: Es complicado dar una respuesta a esto, por que esto ya no depende de la programación sino de la infraestructura (Como este instalado tu servidor, aplicaciones, etc). El siguiente link de pronto te puede servir de algo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32

Comment: En el servidor no aceptan instalar nada de  32bits.

Answer (score 1):

Yo tenía el mismo problema con una aplicación MVC pero, investigando y probando diferentes cosas, lo pude resolver estableciendo la siguiente configuración en el `Web.config` de mi aplicación:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <qualifyAssembly partialName="Oracle.DataAccess" fullName="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Esta solucion no funciono para mi.

Answer (score 1):

Hay que ir a > Herramientas > Administrador de paquetes Nuget para la solución, en la pestaña "Instalado" buscar "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess", a la derecha podemos ver todos los proyectos y la version de ODT instalada, deberían ser homogeneas para no dar este problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he solucionado colocando como configuración en el IIS en el grupo de aplicaciones, seleccionamos en configuración avanzada habilitar aplicaciones en 32 bits = true, esto pasa porque la aplicación inicialmente se pudo haber desarrollado así[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Answer (score 0):

Usé la respuesta de [Raul Reyes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/217877/29444), pero no me funcionó completamente.
Entonces modifiqué el contenido del [AssemblyBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/assemblybinding-element-for-runtime), así:

```cs
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Oracle.DataAccess" publicKeyToken="89b483f429c47342" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.121.1.0" newVersion="4.121.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <qualifyAssembly partialName="Oracle.DataAccess" fullName="Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </assemblyBinding>
```

Si a alguien le funciona con solo '**dependentAssembly**' (eliminando '**qualifyAssembly**'), puede comentarlo o responder.

[QualifyAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/qualifyassembly-element) permite especificar el nombre completo del ensamblado que debe cargarse dinámicamente cuando se usa un nombre parcial.  Mientras que [DependentAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/dependentassembly-element) encapsula la directiva de enlace y la ubicación del ensamblado para cada ensamblado.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).